# Clean a string from whitespace

Tags: java, string

I want to clean String from unnecessary data, something like:

```
x, y, z,  g,  h
```

More precisely, I want delete `g` and `h`, becuase before the g and h character, i have 2 "space".

What is the fastest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String#replaceAll`:

```
String input = "x, y, z,  g,  h";
input = input.replaceAll("\\s{2,}\\w+,?", "");
```

Comment: @YCF_L That didn't fix the problem, assuming that the OP is concerned even about the last comma.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant would be:

```
String data = "x, y, z,  g,  h";
data = Pattern.compile(",")
              .splitAsStream(data)
              .filter(s -> s.length() - s.trim().length() <= 1)
              .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

if for some reason you still want the last comma included then you can do:

```
data = Pattern.compile(",")
              .splitAsStream(data)
              .filter(s -> s.length() - s.trim().length() <= 1)
              .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "", ","));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String str ="x,y,z, g, h;
String newString = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","");
```

o/p:

```
newString = x,y,x,g,h
```

Note: if you want to delete g & h character use java split method.

Comment: You didn't get the problem : _" I want delete g and h, becuase before the g and h character, i have 2 "space"."_ Not simply remove none letters character in a `String`. Your "note" is more likely to be correct but how would you do it with a `split` ?